# jquery datatables custom header hover style

Tags: css, datatables

I have a `jquery datatable` where I create custom logic to display a custom style that I require when the header column lable is in `hover` state.

This is my fiddle:

/* UPDATE FIDDLE WAS NOT THE LAST ONE */
https://jsfiddle.net/y1b6puhn/

[image]

What I need is that the sorting icon is inside my rounded rectangle so it looks fluent and smooth.

So I would like to have something like this where the sorting icon is moved to left a little bit so when you hover you see it in the same position but on top of my rounded rectangle style.:

[image]

Comment: The carat image is in the parent, the background color is in the child. You will not see the image if the child has a background color. You need to rethink the layout of your elements. Also, you are adding padding when you hover which is causing your elements to jump around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit your `.table-rounded-header` a little and it seems to solve it:

```
#example .table-rounded-header {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #dcd9d9;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto; /* for more the one line headers */
    width: 85%; /* instead of 100% */
    text-align: center; /* make it look nicer */
}
```

Hope that solve it.